# Need help to solve this self powers ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, sum

Here is the problem.

> The series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 10<sup>10</sup> = 10405071317.
>
> Find the last ten digits of the series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... +
>   1000<sup>1000</sup>

Here is my code:  The number is so larger it takes a while to process.  Is there a better method to do this?  Can I get the last 10 digits without adding everything up? any thoughts?

This solution works.  But takes a while to process.  Written in Ruby

```
def self_powers

    sum =0

     1.upto(1000).each do |n|
       sum += n**n
     end
    sum
end
```

Comment: Guys- Is there any gem for such calculation ?

Comment: Neil Slater, sorry didn't know how to format the subs

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5E1%2B2%5E2%2B...%2B10%5E10

Comment: @sevenseacat IIRC this was one of the problems on Project Euler.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's correct, and this is one of the rare cases where using a compiled language makes much more sense than using Ruby.

Comment: Ruby's handling of big integers has made this exercise almost pointless. This is the kind of arithmetic IMO it is supposed to invoke: https://gist.github.com/ttezel/4635562 or in Ruby: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, this is pretty direct:

```
sum = 0
(1...1_000).each { |x| sum += x**x }
puts sum % 10**10
```

Comment: @NeilSlater OP uses incorrect format, that's all, it's called **self powers**. I've fixed the format for him.

Comment: Even if you think that is what the OP had in mind, you should not edit the crucial part of the question. You should leave it to the OP. You can only make a guess.

Comment: Yu Hao, formatted very good. Nice, thanks.  This gets the answer directly.

Comment: How is this solution better than what OP has?

Comment: @sawa In general, I agree with you. But for this question, the term *self power* and the code in the question makes it clear. FYI, I only learned the format of 10<sup>10</sup> a while ago. I assume the OP isn't familiar with it, I'll ask in the comment next time though :)

Comment: @tihom.  Try it.  processes instantly.  You get the last 10 digits only.  And you don't have to process the whole thing to get this super long series.

Comment: it would be cool if yo ucan explain it in the answer not able to understand why it is faster than the loop OP had

Comment: Don't those three dots mean this calculates up to `999**999`? In this case doesn't matter because `1000**1000 % 10**10 == 0`

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, I put it there on purpose. A quicker version can omit all numbers like 10,20,30...

Comment: @tihom: Just tried OP's code, seems just as fast to me, at least in Ruby 2.0.0 - the thing added in this answer is the modulus.

Comment: @tihom That's my bad. I wrote some code, tested it, and get the result quickly, and I posted it, and I went to modify the format of the question. Actually OP's code is as quick when I run it.

Comment: @Yu Hoa, Don't know why. it took me .3secs to get the last 10 digits. when I put "sum%10**10. It takes a little while to process the whole series.

Comment: I think Ruby's support for large integers allows a bit of Euler Project non-learning to go on here. A solution using 32-bit arithmetic, and some known way of getting `x**x mod y` would teach a little more.

Answer (score 2):

```
p (1..1000).map{|x|x**x}.inject(:+).to_s[-10,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(1..1000).inject {|tot,x| tot + x**x} % 10**10
```